# How to connect Mongo database to node in MacOs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

I was uploading material for a website on mongo by node previously on my windows pc. Now, I don't have much idea about the technicality of it but all I used to do was open postman, open cmd, type "node index.js", cmd would show "connected to port 3000" and when I used to upload them through postman I could see the changes in Mongo.

Now that I have switched to mac, I don't have much idea how to go about this. I installed mongo, node, and npm using homebrew but I don't know how to set up a local connection between node and mongo to upload to the database.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs-mongodb--how-to-get-connected-to-your-database

Answer (score 0):

ok...I am actually building a APP with MERN stack on Mongodb.

A mac is not much different...sorry a mac is way different-
Postman doesn't work well with mac at all-
Infact I can't even find anything to test a backend with on a mac using Postman from their own official page.

I found this helpful for testing an app with Postman-
https://tech-cookbook.com/2020/04/27/how-to-use-postman-on-mac-os-catalina-get-request-rest-api-example/

It's hard to find sources on Google because it has become a capitalist pig for corporations to sell on....I feel you.
When I started looking for help, I ran into more buy this product than actual tech help.
You can also pull from github repositories...because mac's provide additional security for the users, it's almost guaranteed 20 additional steps in development than a windows.